# Is the water valve continuing to leak after I shut it off normal?

Tags: plumbing

In the process of replacing the T&P valve for my hot water tank, I shut the supply valve off, to the tank but it continued to leak. Is this normal?

Comment: I'm not sure what TP stands for in this context, but old valves often don't close as well as they should. You may need to let it dribble into a bucket during the repair, or find a valve farther back in the supply line that does close properly. (I keep meaning to have a plumber install a second main cut-off that I can operate without fearing that it will fall apart.)

Comment: T&P, temperature and pressure relief valve (HW tank)... I'm guessing.

Comment: What's leaking the shutoff, or the T&P valve?

Comment: Possibly water draining back from the hot pipes, you've only shut off the cold water inlet.

Answer (score 1):

As keshlam points out, old valves don't always seal completely; try to be quick. Also, even if think you've drained the system, it may drip for quite some time. Pipe-fitting doesn't mind a little water; apply dope and screw it on.

Note- The T&P valve is to be piped to near floor level, with no threads left exposed to be perhaps capped by someone; cut them off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're replacing the temperature and pressure (T&P) valve, so I'm just guessing here. A common failure  of T&P valves, is when sediment (or other junk) gets stuck in the valve and holds it open. If this is the case, the valve could potentially leak until the tank is drained below the valve.

Also don't forget, there's a bunch of water in the plumbing running throughout the house. All of that water that is at a higher elevation than the tank, could potentially flow back to the tank when the water pressure is shut off.

Drain the tank to below the valve, and put a bucket under the valve to catch any excess water as you make the repair. T&P valves thread on, so a bit of water isn't going to hurt anything.